# What config changes are being tracked by aureport?

Tags: configuration, audit

I am interested in using aureport to audit my server. When I run:

```
# aureport -c
```

It gives the following output:

```
===================================
# date time type auid success event
===================================
...
35. 05/10/2014 12:34:44 CONFIG_CHANGE -1 yes 6
36. 05/11/2014 12:34:49 MAC_POLICY_LOAD 1000 yes 234
```

However, it doesn't say what `CONFIG_CHANGE` and `MAC_POLICY_LOAD` refers to. And changes I made on some config files in `/etc/` folder doesn't seem to be recorded.

The man page says only:

```
   -c, --config
          Report about config changes
```

Any idea what kind of configuration changes are being tracked by aureport?